# Is Banshee (or other mono applications in Ubuntu) threatened by the recent changes in novell?

Tags: mono

Please inform if the question is off-topic to remove it.

I do not know if I should work with [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) or some other applications since I am afraid that their future is threatened if Mono stops developing. An example: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/is-mono-dead-is-novell-dying/8821.

Are my fears reasonable?

Comment: Novell has been supporting Mono, so while this may hamper development, Mono is open-source, independent contributors can still go ahead making it better.

Answer (score 3):

The core mono team lost their jobs at Novell / Attachmate. However Miguel de Icaza (founder of gnome and the mono project) has taken most of the original team into a mono based startup called [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)

They are committed to contributing to and developing the core opensource mono, this commitment was made in Miguels de Icaza's [blog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/May-16.html).

Since the takeover happened mono 2.10 made it into ubuntu 11.10.